# Plotting a static curve from text file and a real-time curve in one terminal of GNUPLOT

Tags: plot, compare, text-files, gnuplot, curve-fitting

I want to plot two curves in one GnuPlot terminal window so I can see the changes in the terminal window in comparison to both curves.

The first curve consists of a X-Y data (in three columns) taken from a text file (Curve1.txt). The second curve is also taken from another text file (Curve2.txt)but Curve2.txt is the real-time output of a trial application I use. So, when the first step of the trial is converged, it stores the first converge point (x1 y1) in row1 of Curve2.txt. The converging point of step two is stored in row2 of Curve2.txt...and so on during trials. The file size of Curve2.txt continues to be bigger and bigger during trial time depending on how many trials I used.
I want to compare the static curve Curve1.txt with the real-time Curve2.txt in real-time so I know the ongoing difference between both curves in real-time also. Therefore, when steps 3,4,5 plot the third, fourth, and fifth converge points in Curve2.txt, I can see the changes in the terminal window in comparison to Curve1.txt.
FORMAT: Curve1.txt ---- 1 x1 y1
2 x2 y2
...so on
Curve2.txt ---- 1 x1 y1
2 x2 y2
...so on
Can anyone help me with this? I'm only a newbie in coding.
Very much appreciated for the help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Well, we all have been newbies at some point. Here at SO, a reasonable minimum of research effort is expected. What have you tried so far? Please show your initial (non-working) script. Have you consulted the manual, gnuplot homepage or very basic gnuplot tutorials? Maybe you can understand that it will be annoying to answer the hundredth time something like use `plot 'Curve1.txt' u 2:3 w lines, 'Curve2.txt' u 2:3 w lines`. Please read the documentation and come back with a "real problem" or a non-obvious "challenge".

Answer (score 0):

The keywords are `do`, `for` and `pause`. As an example, I have emulated *Curve2.txt* with `ping`:

```
ping www.oszk.hu >> ping.dat
```

(in `bash`). After that, in `Gnuplot`:

```
set datafile separator " ="
do for[i=1:1000]{plot 'Curve1.txt', 'ping.dat' u 7:11; pause 1;}
```

The first line is just for to make my ping data to processable. Also `u 7:11` is just for my file, you should use `u 2:3`. `pause 1` is for 1 second stops between plots.

If you want to plot the two files synchronously, you should use `every`, like:

```
do for[i=1:1000]{plot 'Curve1.txt' every 1::1::i, 'ping.dat' u 7:11; pause 1;}
```